# ajax как обратиться к данным полученным в sucsess

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, можно ли записать данные полученные при помощи ajax в глобальную переменную, для дальнейшего использования их.

```
var ppp = null;
$('#no').on('click', function() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '/show',
        type: 'post',


        success: function(data){

            ppp = data;
            console.log('data', ppp);
        },
        async: false

    });
    console.log(ppp)
})
console.log(ppp)
```

Чтобы они мне были доступны в последнем console.log(ppp)
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: `можно ли записать данные полученные при помощи ajax в глобальную переменную,` -  можно. ты уже это делаешь...

Comment: а что не так то с кодом?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков последний console.log не вывожу уже